# Can p-values from permutation tests be interpreted as a measure of effect size between group?

Tags: statistical-significance, p-value, effect-size, permutation-test

I'm conducting a research project involving gene expression analysis.

We've developed a method to calculate a score from a given set of genes, `A`.
To evaluate the significance of this score in `A`, we calculate an empirical `p-value`. We random select 1,000 similar-sized sets of genes ($Gene\_sets = {R_1, R_2, ..., R_{1000}}$) from the same sample, calculating scores for each ($Scores = {S_1, S_2, ..., S_{1000}}$).

We then count the number of scores larger than the score for `A` ($Score\_a$) in random gene set, divide by the total number of scores in random gene set, and use this as our empirical `p-value`.

$empirical\ P\_value = number\ of\ (Scores > Score\_a)/length(Gene\_sets)$

Initially, We wanted to demonstrate that the higher score of gene set A is not due to random factors.

However, we observed an interesting phenomenon while applying this method. Let's assume we have two groups, `g1` and `g2`, each with three samples (`g1_a, g1_b, g1_c, ...`).

The empirical p-values of all samples are significant. However, p-values vary substantially between groups: p-values for `g1` are `0.001, 0.0003, 0.009`, while p-values for `g2` are `0.01, 0.02, 0.03`, for example.

Since the score measures the strength of an effect in the gene set A, my questions are:

1. Can these p-values be interpreted as measures of effect size? That is, can we say that the effect in the gene set A is stronger in g1 than in g2 based on the p-values?
2. If so, what statistical or mathematical methods should we use to infer this?